# Sencha Architect android build not displaying pictos icons on android 5.1.1+

Tags: android, extjs, android-webview, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have an app made with Sencha Architect 3.2.0 that works fine on android < 5.1.1
On android 5.1.1 and up the icons that are configured with "iconCls" don't appear, instead I get the code of the icon.
If I'm showing the iconCls "home" I get an "H" on the display, "search" gives me "S", checked checkboxes shows a number 3, and so on.

I'm not using any extra icon-font, just the default pictos that comes bundled with sencha architect.

Somehow, pictos is broken for android 5.1.1+ and I can't seem to find a fix for it.
Any help would be appreciated

I build the app with cordova and then install the generated apk on the android devices.

Comment: So is your app native app? Do you use cordova to build your project? Or it's a problem in the browser?

Comment: @pagep yes, I use cordova to build it. And then install the generated apk. I'll add that to question

Comment: What Android 5.1.1 do you use, does your vendor ship a special standard browser?

Comment: Also, which version of Touch do you use? Have you tried packing a test app with the most recent version of Touch?

Comment: Also check if you have latest Cordova version

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just updated the project to sencha cmd 6.2.0.103 and also updated cordova, but this problem is still happening. Android 5.1.1 from Samsung S3 and Moto G @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Try font-src * data:; in your Content-Security-Policy tag (e.g., in index.html).